# Download serverless application from AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, aws-serverless, aws-sam-cli

I have just joined a new project developed entirely on AWS, the project consists of several APIs with Lambda functions grouped in applications.

The thing is that the developer who was in charge of this project is no longer here and I can't contact him. The code is only accessible from the lambda editor, I don't have access to any repository or anything like that. The project seems to have been managed using **SAM client**.

My main issue is that I can download the code for each lambda separately along with its template, but when I make changes locally and try to upload the changes, SAM client detects that the changes I want to make involve uploading the new and deleting all the old, since only that function is included in the template.

Is there any way to download the template of each application (not each function) along with the code? I have looked into `sam sync` command but it seems that it only serves to upload changes from local to AWS, and not the other way around.

This is my first experience with such a project and I don't have much idea how to do it. I would like to have the code on local, manage it through a repository and use SAM client to deploy the changes.

Is this possible? What is the right way to handle a project like this

I have just joined a new project developed entirely on AWS, the project consists of several APIs with Lambda functions grouped in applications.

The thing is that the developer who was in charge of this project is no longer here and I can't contact him. The code is only accessible from the lambda editor, I don't have access to any repository or anything like that. The project seems to have been managed using **SAM client**.

My main issue is that I can download the code for each lambda separately along with its template, but when I make changes locally and try to upload the changes, SAM client detects that the changes I want to make involve uploading the new and deleting all the old, since only that function is included in the template.

Is there any way to download the template of each application (not each function) along with the code? I have looked into `sam sync` command but it seems that it only serves to upload changes from local to AWS, and not the other way around.

This is my first experience with such a project and I don't have much idea how to do it. I would like to have the code on local, manage it through a repository and use SAM client to deploy the changes.

Is this possible? What is the right way to handle a project like this.

**UPDATE**

After download the Cloudformation template, now it seems to detect the other lambdas, but when I try to deploy a new sample lambda (just to check out its working fine), it now detect changes in all lambdas.

Any idea of why it does it?

[image: Stack changeset]

Comment: Those lambda might have a Cloudformation stack have you checked that? and previous developer who commissioned those how did he deploy that infrastructure? Manually?

Comment: I checked the Cloudformation stack, and yes, I can download the template from here. It looks good, I only need to change the `CodeUri` parameter for each lambda to point to the right place. But I noticed that when I make some changes and try to deploy it, it now detects changes in all the lambdas, including the ones I haven't touched yet.

About the previous developer, he is no longer with us, he just left the project without documenting anything and does not pick up the phone. For the meta comments I see in lambdas and Cloudformation he used SAM client.

Comment: Do you know why it detect changes in the other lambdas @Nitink ?

Comment: Does all the lambda code is in one stack only? Lets say you have lambda-1 and lambda-2 do they have different stacks or same one?

Comment: There is one stack per API, each stack contains the API Gateway and all the lambda functions attached to each endpoint (plus all other kind of stuff, like roles, databases, queues... etc).

Comment: Ohk! So what is understood is there is one api which has different resources under it and they point to different lambda's within one stack and you are trying to change the CodeUri in one lambda and it is detecting changes in all. So what is this code uri? is it in your lambda code or the underlying api endpoint itself.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/257032/discussion-between-nitin-k-and-mangelsnc).

Comment: Yes is one API with different resource pointing to different lambdas (all of them grouped under the same app), the `CodeUri` is a parameter of the template I downloaded from Cloudfront, because it was pointing to a S3 bucket (I guess is how it store the lambda code internally), so I changed it to my local path to let  the`sam deploy` command know where are the code.

Comment: So it looks like that parameter is getting used in all lambda? Did you check that. Rather than changing the  parameter try changing in it lambda cloudfromation itself.

Comment: [This is for what `CodeUri` is used for.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-resource-function.html).

In the downloaded template the value points to a S3 resource because the code is already uploaded, but in my local I need to point it to a local path, in order to do the `build` and the `deploy` steps

Comment: ok! So i think that s3 file might have changed as well with new code? So it is showing changes in other lambdas as well. You can check last modified of lambda function and zip of file in s3.

Comment: Not really, I downloaded the current code and I didn't changed anything in those lambdas, I just added a new one.
The expected changes are (look at the screenshot in the main question) all of them except the ones marked in red, because they add a new lambda, a new role, a new permission, a new deployment (removes the previous one) and modify the current API and the Prod stage.
The two functions marked in red are not modified, so I would not change it.